# Calculate colorfulness of Android bitmap

Tags: android

I found a java code of calculate brigntness of Android bitmap

Here :  https://gist.github.com/maxjvh/b1d772caf76cdc0c11e2

But I wonder there is some API that calculate colorfulness or blur of Android bitmap.

I tried but get some std from R,G,B or doing laplacian to R,G,B in java raw code

is some kind of difficult things. Is there is nice Android API? thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by colorfulness or blur? Do you mean Saturation of HSV ?